# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@firebase/firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to connect firebase from my react app. I have installed & reinstalled firebase by `npm install firebase`. But still getting error:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@firebase/firestore ' in 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\crud_firebase\src' **

What should I do now ? How should I conncet to firebase?

I have reinstalled firebase with `npm install firebase` I have deleted all the modules & ran `npm install` But still getting the same error.
My firebase version is "firebase": "^9.15.0".

Comment: Check if the module name is written correctly or not.

Comment: Module name was incorrect.Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`npm i firebase` now installs v9 Modular SDK so you cannot used the old imports. Try refactoring your code to this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

If you want to use older syntax then change your imports to compat libraries:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"
// other services is needed
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).